# Finding a way to tally soccer/football passes in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to take a sequence of passes and show how many times each player passes to another player.

So for example, if the pass sequence was: Jordan to Emma to Molly to Emily bad, that means Jordan's and Emma's passes were successful but Molly's was not.

I have an example of a few lines of data I put in R (in a 2x2 dataset):

```
  Passes
1 jordan to karlie karlie turnover unforced
2 jlin to gray bad
3 alia to kiersten to lilly to kiersten bad
4 mandy to karlie bad
5 kelsey to mccarter to jordan to emma emma fouled
6 mandy to karlie bad
7 mandy to kiersten cleared
```

I am trying to come up with a way that can convert those lines into a table like this:

```
Players Mandy-G Jlin-G Gray-G Kiersten-G Kelsey-G Karlie-G Jordan-G Lilly-G Mccarter-G Emma-G Alia-G Mandy-B Jlin-B Gray-B Kiersten-B Kelsey-B Karlie-B Jordan-B Lilly-B Mccarter-B Emma-B Alia-B
Mandy                             1                                                                                                              2
Jlin                                                                                                                   1
Gray
Kiersten                                                               1
Kelsey                                                                          1
Karlie
Jordan                                               1                                    1
Lilly                                                                                                                          1
McCarter                                                      1
Emma
Alia                              1
```

*I don't know how to insert a screenshot, so the copy and paste messed up the formatting but you can still get the idea of what I want it to look like.

If Mandy passed to Gray and it was good there should be a 1 in the Mandy and Gray-G intersection. If Mandy passed to Gray and it was bad there should be a 1 in the Mandy and Gray-B intersection.

There are only numbers in that table because I did it by hand and it was only for about 10 minutes of a game. Ultimately, doing it for the full 90 minutes and for about 25 games, I'm going to need to create a way to go through the first table and have R sort and add a mark for each successful and unsuccessful pass.

```
dat3 <- strsplit(dat[,1], "to")
numPass <- rep(0, length(dat3))

for (i in 1:length(dat2)) {
  temp <- sum(dat2[[i]] == "to")
  if ("bad" %in% dat2[[i]]) {
    temp <- temp-1
  }
  numPass[i] <- temp
}
maxPass <- max(numPass)+1


#for (i in 1:length(dat2)){
for (i in 5){
  keep<-dat2[[i]]%in%roster[,1]
  pls<-dat2[[i]][keep]
  #add statemets to remove last name if there is a "bad"
  for (j in 1:length(pls)) {
      cols<-which(substr(names(seqPass),1,nchar(pls[j]))==pls[j])
      seqPass[i,cols[j]]<-j

  }
}

seqPass[c(1,5),]
```

I have tried the above code to go through the first five lines and to count the number of passes in each sequence and it adds a mark under each player's name if they were involved in the pass, but if it was bad they need to be removed which is does not do.

Is there a way for R to automatically count if the first name and second name in the sequence have a good pass, add a mark in their intersection, and do the same for if the first and second name make a bad pass by having the word "bad" follows the second name?

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

#### Sample data

```
structure(list(VT = c("jordan to karlie karlie turnover unforced", 
"jlin to gray bad", "alia to kiersten to lilly to kiersten bad", 
"mandy to karlie bad", "kelsey to mccarter to jordan to emma emma fouled", 
"mandy to karlie bad", "mandy to kiersten cleared bad")), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(8:19, .Names = c("8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"
), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: The text table is **much** better than a screen shot, but it would be nice if you would edit the spacing so that it is accurate.

Comment: @Gregor this is my first post on stack overflow, so I was confused on how the formatting works, otherwise I would have edited the spacing. Can I send you a screenshot of the table from Excel if you have an idea on what I am asking in my question?

Comment: No, screenshots are annoying to work with. Text is much nicer. Please just edit the spacing of the table in your question. Click the "edit" button at the bottom of your question and make the changes.

Comment: [This may help you copy out of Excel more successfully](https://superuser.com/a/522795/164122)

Comment: Also, why the Java tag? Do you not care if there's a solution in Java or in R?

Comment: @Gregor ok I have it all formatted now - is it more clear to read or is there anything else I should do to make it easier to see?

Comment: @Gregor I ideally prefer R, I only added the Java tag in case someone thought the solution would be easier in Java. *hope it is in R though. I'm new to stack so I added java just in case :p

Comment: Much better, thanks. The other thing that would be really nice is giving us input in a format that can by copy/pasted into R. Either share the code for your sample data or use `dput()` on it to make a copy/pasteable representation.

Comment: structure(list(VT = c("jordan to karlie karlie turnover unforced", 
"jlin to gray bad", "alia to kiersten to lilly to kiersten bad", 
"mandy to karlie bad", "kelsey to mccarter to jordan to emma emma fouled", 
"mandy to karlie bad", "mandy to kiersten cleared bad")), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(8:19, .Names = c("8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"
), class = "omit"))            I used dput() on the data - is this what you meant? @Gregor

Comment: That's great, edit it into your question so it's visible for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions. And Also it will be fast if you only put the data of those who touched the ball. So something like:

```
pass = sub('_$','_good',sub("(.*\\w+ to (?:\\w+(?=.*(bad))|\\w+)).*",'\\1_\\2',dat$VT,perl = T))
pass1 = gsub('(to(\\s[^_ ]+(?=\\s)))','\\1_good\n\\2',pass,perl=T)
results = xtabs(V3~.,cbind(read.csv(text=gsub('to',',',pass1),h=F,strip.white = T),V3=1))

results
          V2
V1         emma_good gray_bad jordan_good karlie_bad karlie_good kiersten_bad kiersten_good lilly_good mccarter_good
  alia             0        0           0          0           0            0             1          0             0
  jlin             0        1           0          0           0            0             0          0             0
  jordan           1        0           0          0           1            0             0          0             0
  kelsey           0        0           0          0           0            0             0          0             1
  kiersten         0        0           0          0           0            0             0          1             0
  lilly            0        0           0          0           0            1             0          0             0
  mandy            0        0           0          2           0            1             0          0             0
  mccarter         0        0           1          0           0            0             0          0             0
```

Comment: thanks so much that helps a lot. also i was wondering is there a way I can combine other stats into that table such as intercepted passes (I have it under the column "PI"), tackles, cleared, fouls, etc.? I have put a second sample code in my original question to show what I am asking. I just don't know how I would what I am looking for into the code you provided. Thanks, Sam

Comment: @samrizz4 Since this is an old question, you would need to ask a new one with the new dataset No one will be digging into the past to try and help you solve the question. You better ask a new one with the new dataset

Comment: Thanks, sorry I am new to this website so I didn't know that is how that worked, and since you helped with the first question I thought replying here would work too. But I just made a new post asking the newer question for others to see as well. Thanks again. Sam

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have done a lot of the work already, so I will just add in my two cents. It would make your table generally smaller if you didn't separate out good and bad as two tables. You could generally have one table with combinations of players like you have created, but add a column with a 1 or 0 stating if the pass was good or bad, in which case you could just have your code above but with

```
dat$pass <- as.numeric(grepl(".*(bad)", dat$VT))
```

This adds a column with 1 if the row has 'bad' in it. Imagine the complexity of a good and bad table over multiple decades and different players!

Comment: Hi thanks. I am kind of confused on what you are suggesting to do. I used your line of code, and then I did: other <- dat$pass and other gives me the following:  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0. I'm guessing I'm missing something based on what you are saying to do, since I don't know how that "adds a column with 1 if the row has the word bad in it". Let me know if I was doing something wrong. Thanks, Sam

Comment: You would just add this on after reading in your original data structure, so dat=structure(list(VT=...)), then this line. It'll create a new column called 'pass' in 'dat' data frame.